# Getting the highest value of an JSON array and storing it in Data Vue

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my vue component i have a json array of Bids.

[image]

I need to get the highest bid from the array and store it into another variable.

My vue component data:

```
data() {
  return {
    bids: [],
    bid: null,

    veiling_id: this.id,
    showInput: this.auth_check,

     highestBid: null,
  }
},
```

Getting the bids from DB and storing into bids.

```
mounted(){
    var veilingid = this.veiling_id;
    var vm = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        axios.get('/veilingen/' + veilingid + '/getbid').
        then(function (response){
            vm.bids = response.data;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
     }, 1000);

 }
```

And now how do i loop through Bids, get the highest bid and store it into highestBid?

Also what's the best place to store the code?

Right after the AXIOS get request in the mounted() or somewhere else?

I'm sorry i'n new to Vue.

Any help is appreciated..

Requested JSON:

```
"[{"id":1,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"100.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:24:20","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:24:20"},{"id":2,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"40.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:43:11","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:43:11"},{"id":3,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"3.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:43:34","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:43:34"},{"id":4,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"4.34","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:44:32","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:44:32"},{"id":5,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"900.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:44:49","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:44:49"},{"id":6,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"90.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:51:55","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:51:55"},{"id":7,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"90.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:53:10","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:53:10"},{"id":8,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"3.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:53:18","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:53:18"},{"id":9,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"3.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 20:53:59","updated_at":"2017-08-31 20:53:59"},{"id":10,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"50.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 21:03:17","updated_at":"2017-08-31 21:03:17"},{"id":11,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"1000.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-08-31 21:05:35","updated_at":"2017-08-31 21:05:35"},{"id":12,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"2000.00","user_id":2,"created_at":"2017-09-01 00:07:19","updated_at":"2017-09-01 00:07:19"},{"id":13,"veiling_id":1,"bid":"3.00","user_id":1,"created_at":"2017-09-01 00:28:56","updated_at":"2017-09-01 00:28:56"}]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great use case for a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

```
computed:{
  highestBid(){
    if (this.bids.length == 0) return 
    return this.bids.reduce((a,b) => Number(a.bid) > Number(b.bid) ? a : b)    
  }
},
```

Here is an example of how that would work.

```js
console.clear()

const bids = [
  {bid: 2000},
  {bid: 1000},
  {bid: 3000},
  {bid: 4000},
  {bid: 100},
  
]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      bids: [],
    }
  },
  computed:{
    highestBid(){
      if (this.bids.length == 0) return 
      return this.bids.reduce((a,b) => Number(a.bid) > Number(b.bid) ? a : b)     
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.bids = bids
    }, 250)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{highestBid}}
</div>
```

In the above example, whenever `bids` is populated or changes, `highestBid` will return the bid object with the highest value. The `setTimeout` is just simulating the ajax call.

You can perform your API call in either mounted or created.

Note also I noticed that you are returning your bid values as strings so the code uses `Number()` to convert them to numbers. There are *many* ways to convert to numeric values in javascript and you can investigate the best way that works for you.

Comment: I can't get `if (this.bids.length == 0) return 
      this.bids.reduce((a,b) => Number(a.bid) > Number(b.bid) ? a : b) ` to work somehow, it's return 900 when the highest bid is 2000

Comment: @JordyGroote Can you provide an actual example of your JSON? I'll update with it.

Comment: I updated the answer the JSON is at the bottom. @Bert

Comment: @JordyGroote Hm. Browser issue? This seems to work fine. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mMvyVB?editors=1010

Comment: I see, ugh Vue is so hard to learn. Now it completely disappeard and is returning nothing.... Struggles!!!!

Comment: @JordyGroote I've had the opposite experience :) I'm sure it's something simple. Post the whole component? Remember you need to remove `highestBid` from data.

Comment: It's magicly working now. Must've missed a small thing.. Maybe it's time for bed. Thanks for you help. Will approve your answer.

Comment: @JordyGroote Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 //params is object
 findWinConfirmed(topConfirmed) {
  let findTop = [];
  topConfirmed.data.forEach(obj => findTop.push(obj.bid));
  return Math.max(...findTop);
}
```

Hope is help.